# How set Vue inputs via phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phantomjs

The code like that:

```
document.getElementById('email').value = 'login';
document.getElementById('password').value = 'pwd';
document.getElementById('button').click();
```

does not work because Vue uses `v-model` value instead of `value` attribute. Is there a way to change input and model values via javascript in phantomjs?

**Notes**

1. Setting attribute `v-model` for those input do not solve the
   problem.
2. Using `CSP-compliant-build` is not possible, because I can not rebuild  project from sources.
3. Any extension for chrome also can not be used because page is rendered via phantomjs

Comment: Have you tried triggering a 'change' event (or calling the change handler directly) on those fields after setting the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS [supports sending "real" keypress](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) events to the page. You need to focus the necessary field first, then type to it:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById("#email").focus();
});
page.sendEvent('keypress', 'login');

page.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById("#password").focus();
});
page.sendEvent('keypress', 'pwd');

page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Enter);
```